# Como pasar la variable de una funcion a la condicion IN en Postgresql

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, funciones, variables

Tengo una función en **postgresql 10** que recibe varios parámetros, uno de ellos es un **varchar** que tiene los **códigos(id)** entre comas que dicho valor utiliza para filtrar los resultados de una tabla mediante la **condición IN**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION redcobrosjp.test_reporte_2(vidred bigint, vidrecaudador character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF redcobrosjp.trx_report_recaudador
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    
BEGIN
    
   return query 
   SELECT 
           TO_CHAR(rc.fecha_ingreso, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::TEXT AS fecha,
           rc.moneda AS moneda,
           rc.nro_gestion AS lote
      FROM redcobrosjp.red_recaudador rc 
     WHERE rc.anulado = 'N'   
       AND ( vidrecaudador IS NULL
            OR
            rc.id_recaudador IN (vidrecaudador))
            
    ORDER BY 1;

END;
$function$
;
```

Lo ejecuto de la siguiente forma:

SELECT *
FROM redcobrosjp.test_reporte_2(
1,
'11,27'::varchar);

El problema se da en la linea:

```
rc.id_recaudador IN (vidrecaudador)
```

El error que lanza es:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: el operador no existe: bigint = character
> varying   Hint: Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de
> los argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de
> tipos.   Where: función PL/pgSQL
> redcobrosjp.test_reporte_2(bigint,character varying) en la línea 6 en
> RETURN QUERY

La columna id_recaudador es un bigint, pero no si realizo un cast a varchar pierdo rendimiento

Existe alguna forma de solucionar esto y de ser posible que se mantenga el rendimiento(utilizando siempre el indice)?

Comment: Buenas, Mathias, ¿has probado a construir la consulta como si fuera una cadena y luego ejecutarla? Se hace empleando EXECUTE dentro de la función. Aquí tienes alguna referencia al respecto (en inglés) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 0):

Debes tratar de convertir ese `varchar` a un conjunto de `bigint` en este caso puedes utilizar la combinación de las funciones  `unnest` y `string_to_array` para tu comparacion en la condicion de `IN`, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION redcobrosjp.test_reporte_2(vidred bigint, vidrecaudador character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF redcobrosjp.trx_report_recaudador
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    
BEGIN
    
   return query 
   SELECT 
           TO_CHAR(rc.fecha_ingreso, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::TEXT AS fecha,
           rc.moneda AS moneda,
           rc.nro_gestion AS lote
      FROM redcobrosjp.red_recaudador rc 
     WHERE rc.anulado = 'N'   
       AND ( vidrecaudador IS NULL
            OR
            rc.id_recaudador IN (SELECT unnest (string_to_array(vidrecaudador,','))::int)
            
    ORDER BY 1;

END;
$function$
;
```